# Forecast proportions through time

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting

I want to predict/forecast the proportion of positives (sample testing positive) over a 1-3-6 month period. My data has a lot of negative sample tests, therefore, it's aggregated by month. Let's assume I have this data, which is similar to what I have.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates = ['2021-07', '2014-10', '2014-07', '2015-04', '2023-07', '2006-08', '2014-04', '2022-02', '2019-03', '2016-04', '2013-09', '2013-05', '2015-01', '2014-03', '2012-05', '2021-08', '2016-11', '2013-06', '2020-05', '2006-05', '2019-06', '2008-07', '2017-11', '2016-06', '2005-10', '2009-04', '2018-04', '2005-12', '2023-02', '2013-04', '2013-07', '2015-09', '2017-08', '2012-02', '2023-06', '2020-07', '2008-06', '2007-09', '2018-09', '2015-07', '2011-10', '2014-09', '2021-09', '2008-02', '2009-10', '2007-10', '2016-05', '2022-06', '2008-09', '2005-09']
positives = [2, 10, 13, 16, 7, 21, 9, 0, 10, 18, 11, 2, 2, 3, 3, 18, 14, 3, 20, 17, 18, 14, 9, 1, 4, 10, 22, 11, 8, 11, 2, 19, 16, 0, 22, 0, 6, 19, 14, 10, 19, 8, 13, 2, 3, 2, 11, 13, 16, 8]
totals = [122, 69, 145, 122, 117, 111, 64, 146, 54, 189, 136, 171, 159, 125, 66, 199, 160, 75, 171, 168, 167, 133, 154, 171, 120, 81, 63, 121, 129, 91, 68, 90, 61, 161, 143, 179, 168, 94, 175, 74, 117, 53, 85, 93, 82, 61, 154, 188, 175, 161]
countries = ['Spain', 'Brazil', 'Mexico', 'United Kingdom', 'Italy', 'Germany', 'Mexico', 'Argentina', 'Germany', 'Mexico', 'Mexico', 'Italy', 'United Kingdom', 'United Kingdom', 'United Kingdom', 'Italy', 'Mexico', 'Brazil', 'Mexico', 'United Kingdom', 'Italy', 'Italy', 'Germany', 'Canada', 'Brazil', 'Brazil', 'Spain', 'Canada', 'Germany', 'Spain', 'Argentina', 'United States', 'Brazil', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'United States', 'Spain', 'Canada', 'Canada', 'United States', 'Mexico', 'Spain', 'Spain', 'Argentina', 'Argentina', 'United States', 'United Kingdom', 'Mexico', 'Italy', 'Mexico']
food_groups = ['Sausages', 'Ready-to-Eat', 'Ready-to-Eat', 'Sausages', 'Ready-to-Eat', 'Infant Food', 'Sausages', 'Infant Food', 'Infant Food', 'Sausages', 'Pasta', 'Pasta', 'Ready-to-Eat', 'Sausages', 'Infant Food', 'Pasta', 'Pasta', 'Ready-to-Eat', 'Ready-to-Eat', 'Ready-to-Eat', 'Ready-to-Eat', 'Sausages', 'Meat', 'Pasta', 'Ready-to-Eat', 'Infant Food', 'Pasta', 'Ready-to-Eat', 'Ready-to-Eat', 'Sausages', 'Meat', 'Meat', 'Sausages', 'Infant Food', 'Meat', 'Infant Food', 'Pasta', 'Pasta', 'Meat', 'Meat', 'Pasta', 'Pasta', 'Meat', 'Pasta', 'Sausages', 'Ready-to-Eat', 'Ready-to-Eat', 'Sausages', 'Ready-to-Eat', 'Pasta']

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "date": dates,
    "positive": positives,
    "total": totals,
    "country": countries,
    'food_group': food_groups
})
df["p"] = df["positive"] / df["total"]

df
```

[image]

What machine learning model could I use? My data is highly imbalanced, any ideas on how I could approach this?

Comment: If your outcome is the proportions of positive somethings `'p'` (range [0,1]), then you wouldn't have a classification problem and it's not as obvious imbalance is an issue. Initially I thought you could try linear regression (still can as a base model), but there are some ideas [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/457889/predicting-proportions-with-machine-learning) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/273428/best-way-to-model-a-regression-with-proportions-as-dependent-variable).